# Custome UITableViewCell objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have UILabel and UIImageView at same frames and I'm using separate UITableViewCell xib for both iPhone & iPad. I'm hiding image view and showing UILabel alone. In iPad UILabel is not shown.

Pls help me.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: yes
if (addMenuIconArray == (id)[NSNull null] || (addMenuIconArray.count == 0))
        {
            [cell.MenuIconImg setHidden:YES];
            [cell.MenuIconLbl setHidden:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.MenuIconImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[addMenuIconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
            [cell.MenuIconImg setHidden:NO];
            [cell.MenuIconLbl setHidden:YES];
        }

Comment: if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: IS_IPAD ? @"ActivityViewCell" : @"ActivityViewCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
            
            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell =  (ActivityViewCell *) [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

This question and shared code are not enough to see how you do iPad handling differently from iPhone handling. You could debug by placing a breakpoint at the end of your method and watch for values like label's visibility, hidden and frame properties. At least that will give an indication of whether the label is hidden, out of bounds or simply has a size of (0, 0).

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActivityMenu";
        ActivityViewCell *cell = (ActivityViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: IS_IPAD ? @"ActivityViewCell" : @"ActivityViewCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
            
            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {cell =  (ActivityViewCell *) [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]; break; }} }

Comment: I debugged and checked. Label frame is coming but it is not shown

Comment: Maybe another element is covering up the label such as the image view.

Comment: Okay..i'll check it